# Justify Nav-pills with Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I want to justify my navigation bar across the width of the div. The trouble is that I use `Bootstrap v4` and the **nav-justify** class is not yet available.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#subscribed" data-toggle="tab">Mes inscriptions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventPassed" data-toggle="tab">Événements passés</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventNow" data-toggle="tab">Événements en cours</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventIncoming" data-toggle="tab">Événements futurs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventCreation" data-toggle="tab">Créer un événement</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventOwn" data-toggle="tab">Mes événements</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I do not want to use percentages in CSS to do this ; I want something that is responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

indeed the `nav-justify class` is missing. You can add it yourself based on TB3's code for now:

**SCSS code:**

```
// Justified nav links
// -------------------------

@mixin nav-justified {
  width: 100%;

  .nav-item {
    float: none;
  }

  .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  > .dropdown .dropdown-menu { //todo: remove child selector
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    .nav-item {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 1%;
    }
    .nav-link {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}

// Move borders to anchors instead of bottom of list
//
// Mixin for adding on top the shared `.nav-justified` styles for our tabs
@mixin nav-tabs-justified {
  border-bottom: 0;

  .nav-link {
    // Override margin from .nav-tabs
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: $border-radius;
  }

  .nav-link.active,
  .nav-link.active:hover,
  .nav-link.active:focus {
    border: 1px solid $nav-tabs-justified-link-border-color;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    .nav-link {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $nav-tabs-justified-link-border-color;
      border-radius: $border-radius $border-radius 0 0;
    }
   .nav-link.active,
   .nav-link.active:hover,
   .nav-link.active:focus {
      border-bottom-color: $nav-tabs-justified-active-link-border-color;
    }
  }
}

.nav-justified {
  @include nav-justified;
  @include nav-tabs-justified;
}
```

**compiled CSS code:**

```
.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0; }
  .nav-justified .nav-item {
    float: none; }
  .nav-justified .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px; }
  .nav-justified > .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    top: auto;
    left: auto; }
  @media (min-width: 544px) {
    .nav-justified .nav-item {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 1%; }
    .nav-justified .nav-link {
      margin-bottom: 0; } }
  .nav-justified .nav-link {
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0.25rem; }
  .nav-justified .nav-link.active,
  .nav-justified .nav-link.active:hover,
  .nav-justified .nav-link.active:focus {
    border: 1px solid #ddd; }
  @media (min-width: 544px) {
    .nav-justified .nav-link {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 0; }
    .nav-justified .nav-link.active,
    .nav-justified .nav-link.active:hover,
    .nav-justified .nav-link.active:focus {
      border-bottom-color: #fff; } }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**large screens**
[image]

**small screen**
[image]

UPDATE: As of BS4 alpha 6, the `nav-justified` is back, along with a new class `nav-fill` http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#fill-and-justify

Comment: I need to change 2-3 things but it's exactly what I need. I will change the breakpoint to **md**. I just need to install SCSS compilator. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

As of Bootstrap alpha 6, `nav-justified` is back, and there is a new `nav-fill` class.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#fill-and-justify

You just need to add the class to your `nav`..

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        ..
</ul>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Justified Nav](http://www.codeply.com/go/t6EpPvoacQ)

Answer (score 1):

They had it in the documentation of Boostrap `v.4` `alpha`, [on this page](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/), but now it's broken.

There's corresponding [ticket for this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17723), and there is already created [pull request for `v4-dev` branch](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/18653).

To post the whole code snippet here, makes no sense, so [the changes you may see here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/18653/files), and to patch yourself your SASS file:

```scss
// Justified nav links
// -------------------------

@mixin nav-justified {
  width: 100%;

  .nav-item {
    float: none;
  }

  .nav-link {
    margin-bottom: $nav-tabs-justified-link-margin-bottom;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    .nav-item {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 1%;
    }
    .nav-link {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}

// Move borders to anchors instead of bottom of list
//
// Mixin for adding on top the shared `.nav-justified` styles for our tabs
@mixin nav-tabs-justified {
  border-bottom: 0;

  .nav-link { // Override margin from .nav-tabs
    margin-right: 0;
    @include border-radius($nav-tabs-justified-link-border-radius);
  }

  .nav-link.active {
    @include plain-hover-focus {
      border: $nav-tabs-justified-link-border-width solid $nav-tabs-justified-link-border-color;
    }
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    .nav-link,
    .nav-link.disabled,
    .nav-link.disabled:hover {
      border-bottom: $nav-tabs-justified-link-border-width solid $nav-tabs-justified-link-border-color;
      @include border-top-radius($nav-tabs-justified-link-border-radius);
    }
    .nav-link.active {
      @include plain-hover-focus {
        border-bottom-color: $nav-tabs-justified-active-link-border-color;
      }
    }
  }
}
```