# "nav nav-pills nav-justified" class not stacking the tabs for mobile views

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am using the latest bootstrap version in angular. The class "nav nav-pills nav-justified" not stacking the tabs when the screen size is reduced below 768px.

I referred to the site http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/73rNv/. which is in the post. In stack overflow I followed [Justify Nav-pills with Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411884/justify-nav-pills-with-bootstrap-v4) but it does work too

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" routerLink="/">Feeds</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/status-update']">Status Update</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/goal-setting']">Goal Setting</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/meet-up']">Meet up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

[image: desktop view]
[image: mobile view not stacking]

I can't understand why it works in http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/73rNv/ here and the same code fails in my case. Please advice.

Comment: can you verify if bootstrap css and the js is loading on your page ?

Comment: Yes. They are loading well. Other bootstrap classes are working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On analysis we find that:

- The Bootstrap version in http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/73rNv/ is 3.1.1
- The Bootstrap version from the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411884/justify-nav-pills-with-bootstrap-v4) example was unknown (post was dated 2015), but there was an update which referred to [this page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/)
- we see that classes `nav-pills nav-fill` are available in BS4... to get the pills from the navigation on their each separate line, we can write some CSS ourselves

working **snippet on Bootstrap 4.3.1** below:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-fill .nav-item {
    width: 100% !important;
    flex-basis: unset !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give a try with this.

Comment: You're welcome... do accept the answer if it works for you... else share the outcome and i'll try to help

Comment: This works exactly fine!. This says that functionality of nav-justified has been deprecated in the latest version of bootstrap.